# Macro to Search for a string in a work book which may present multiple times

Tags: search, excel-2007, excel

I have a workbook where there are 5 sheets and 500 rows each. I want a macro which can search for the string which may present multiple time in the workbook. Please help me with this.

Regards,
MDS

Answer (score 0):

What do you want it to do when it finds the string?  The non-macro method is Edit - Find and click the Options button.  Set "within" to Workbook and click Find All.  That will give you a list of all of the strings found.

If you really want a macro, this one will print the locations to the Immediate Window.

```
Sub FindAll()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sFirst As String
    Dim sWhat as String

    sWhat = Application.InputBox("Search for:")

    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set rFound = sh.UsedRange.Find(sWhat, , xlValues, xlPart)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            sFirst = rFound.Address
            Debug.Print rFound.Address(, , , True)
            Do
                Set rFound = sh.UsedRange.FindNext(rFound)
                If rFound Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                Debug.Print rFound.Address(, , , True)
            Loop Until rFound.Address = sFirst
        End If
    Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Dick, Thank you for your response. Actually I wanted a macro which will open a window asking for search string and upon giving which it will locate the string with in whole workbook. If there are multiple entries I want it to locate all of them one by one. please help.